# Why Python MySQL Insert into the table not working?

Tags: python, mariadb, aio-mysql

I am using **aiomysql** and **MariaDB**. I can create a table or select data, but I can't insert data into the table. If you `SELECT` data with `fetchall()`, then it will show what you just inserted, but immediately delete from the database.

```
async def test_example(loop):
    pool = await aiomysql.create_pool(host='127.0.0.1', port=3306,
                                      user='root', password='',
                                      db='test', loop=loop)
    async with pool.acquire() as conn:
        async with conn.cursor() as cur:
            await cur.execute("INSERT INTO `tbl`(`id`, `val`) VALUES (37, 'z');")
            print(cur.fetchall())
    pool.close()
    await pool.wait_closed()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(test_example(loop))
```

Why?

Comment: What do you expect a fetchall() to return after an insert?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a detailed description of the error

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remove the quotes from the table and column names.

```
import aiomysql
import asyncio


async def select(loop, sql, pool):
    async with pool.acquire() as conn:
        async with conn.cursor() as cur:
            await cur.execute(sql)
            r = await cur.fetchone()
            print(r)


async def insert(loop, sql, pool):
    async with pool.acquire() as conn:
        async with conn.cursor() as cur:
            await cur.execute(sql)
            await conn.commit()


async def main(loop):
    pool = await aiomysql.create_pool(host='127.0.0.1', port=3306,
                                      user='root', password='',
                                      db='test', loop=loop)
    c1 = select(loop=loop, sql='select * from tbl', pool=pool)
    c2 = insert(loop=loop, sql="INSERT INTO tbl(id, val) VALUES (37, 'z');", pool=pool)

    tasks = [asyncio.ensure_future(c1), asyncio.ensure_future(c2)]
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cur_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    cur_loop.run_until_complete(main(cur_loop))
```

Comment: It did not help

Comment: I can get data, but I cannot insert it for some reason

Comment: @Dmitriy  see the updated answer you are missing `cur.commit()`

Comment: and **I tried this too**, now I have checked all the cursor attributes again, **it doesn't have such an attribute**. Most likely this is due to the fact that everywhere in StackOverflow answers there is synchronous code.

Comment: @Dmitriy use `.cursor(prepared=True)` to define `cur`.

Comment: how? I didn't quite understand

Comment: @Dmitriy the line in the updated answer `async with conn.cursor(prepared=True) as cur:`

Comment: `TypeError: cursor() got an unexpected keyword argument 'prepared'`

Comment: What!  Run two queries asynchronously?  Doesn't that mean that the `SELECT` might run _before_ the `INSERT`?  In that case, the select would correctly be empty.

Answer (score 1):

From the [PEP-249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) specification:

**.fetchall()**

*Fetch all (remaining) rows of a query result, returning them as a sequence of sequences (e.g. a list of tuples).*

Since sql `INSERT` statement doesn't produce a result set you should try a `SELECT` statement before trying to obtain information from the database server.

Comment: I know this, the select works, I am interested in the question with insertion into the table

Comment: @Dmitriy - There are no results from an `INSERT`, hence nothing to display.  Sure, the _table_ has some results; but you cannot see them without using a `SELECT`.